# UIImageView and UIScrollView zooming

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uiscrollview

Do I actually need a UIPinchGestureRecognizer inside a UIScrollView to have the pinch working? If yes how do I do it? I am trying to implement what flipboard has, where it basically zooms in an image and have the scroll capability after zooming in. How do I do that?

**UPDATE:**

Here's some code that I have which doesn't call the scroll view delegate

```
CGRect imgFrame;
imgFrame.size.width = originalImageSize.width;
imgFrame.size.height = originalImageSize.height;
imgFrame.origin.x = imageOriginPoint.x;
imgFrame.origin.y = imageOriginPoint.y;

NSData *data = [request responseData];
UIImage * image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
[imageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[imageView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[imageView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
[imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, imgFrame.size.width, imgFrame.size.height)];

UIScrollView * imgScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:imageView.frame];
imgScrollView.delegate = self;
imgScrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
imgScrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
[imgScrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
[imgScrollView setClipsToBounds:YES];
[imgScrollView addSubview:imageView];
[imgScrollView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
[imgScrollView setMaximumZoomScale:1.0];
```

Answer (score 96, accepted):

All you need to do is add your `UIImageView` (or any view you want to zoom) inside your `UIScrollView`.

Set your `maximumZoomScale` on your `UIScrollView` to any value higher than 1.0f.

Set yourself as the delegate of your `UIScrollView` and return the `UIImageView` in the viewForZooming delegate method.

That's it. No pinch gesture needed, no nothing. `UIScrollView` handles pinch zooming for you.

Comment: yea, I did all that but the delegate is not called

Comment: aha! I didn't set the maxZoomScale and therefore it didn't work! thanks

Comment: Ignacio please can you tell the constraints on imageView and scrollView. I did the same but it is not working. My image view is set to aspect fill and width are going outside from the image View frame so I need to increase image view frame as well as scroll view content size width. I have only one image in my scroll view

Comment: in case you need zoom out feature, just set the minimumZoomScale property as well.

Comment: Also note when adding the UIImageView to the scroll view, don't set any layout constraint on it.

Answer (score 20):

**Objective C**

**Pinch-zoom Image in Scrollview Steps (Objective C)**

**1. Scroll View Constraints**

[image]

**2. Add ImageView In ScrollView and set Constraints**

[image]

**3. Take IBOutlets**

```
IBOutlet UIScrollView * bgScrollView;
IBOutlet UIImageView * imageViewOutlet;
```

**4. viewDidLoad Method**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
 {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    float minScale=bgScrollView.frame.size.width / imageViewOutlet.frame.size.width;
    bgScrollView.minimumZoomScale = minScale;
    bgScrollView.maximumZoomScale = 3.0;
    bgScrollView.contentSize = imageViewOutlet.frame.size;
    bgScrollView.delegate = self;
}
```

**5. Scroll View Delegate Method**

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    return imageViewOutlet;
}
```

**Swift**

**Pinch-zoom Image in Scrollview Steps (Swift)**

**1. Scroll View Constraints**

[image]

**2. Add ImageView In ScrollView and set Constraints**

[image]

**3. Take IBOutlets**

```
@IBOutlet weak var bgScrollView : UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet weak var imageView : UIImageView!
```

**4. viewDidLoad Method**

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let minScale = bgScrollView.frame.size.width / imageView.frame.size.width;
    bgScrollView.minimumZoomScale = minScale
    bgScrollView.maximumZoomScale = 3.0
    bgScrollView.contentSize = imageView.frame.size
    bgScrollView.delegate = self
}
```

**5. Scroll View Delegate Method**

```
func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
    return imageView
}
```

Answer (score 14):

I did a custom image viewer not a long ago without the pinch recognizers. Just UIImageView on top of UIScrollView. There you pass a string with a link to the image and it also has a progress bar. Once that image is finished loading the image is shown. Here's the code:

```
-(UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
  return self.theImageView;
}

- (CGRect)centeredFrameForScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scroll andUIView:(UIView *)rView {
  CGSize boundsSize = scroll.bounds.size;
  CGRect frameToCenter = rView.frame;
  // center horizontally
  if (frameToCenter.size.width < boundsSize.width) {
    frameToCenter.origin.x = (boundsSize.width - frameToCenter.size.width) / 2;
  }
  else {
    frameToCenter.origin.x = 0;
  }
  // center vertically
  if (frameToCenter.size.height < boundsSize.height) {
    frameToCenter.origin.y = (boundsSize.height - frameToCenter.size.height) / 2;
  }
  else {
    frameToCenter.origin.y = 0;
  }
  return frameToCenter;
}

-(void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
  self.theImageView.frame = [self centeredFrameForScrollView:self.theScrollView andUIView:self.theImageView];                               
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
  [self.resourceData setLength:0];
  self.filesize = [NSNumber numberWithLongLong:[response expectedContentLength]];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
  [self.resourceData appendData:data];
  NSNumber *resourceLength = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:[self.resourceData length]];
  self.progressBar.progress = [resourceLength floatValue] / [self.filesize floatValue];
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
  self.theImage = [[UIImage alloc]initWithData:resourceData];
  self.theImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.theImage.size.width, self.theImage.size.height);
  self.theImageView.image = self.theImage;
  self.theScrollView.minimumZoomScale = self.theScrollView.frame.size.width / self.theImageView.frame.size.width;
  self.theScrollView.maximumZoomScale = 2.0;
  [self.theScrollView setZoomScale:self.theScrollView.minimumZoomScale];
  self.theScrollView.contentSize = self.theImageView.frame.size;
  self.theLabel.hidden = YES;
  self.progressBar.hidden = YES;
}

-(void)setImageInImageView
{
  NSURLRequest *req = [[NSURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.imageLink]];
  NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:req delegate:self];
  if (conn)
  {
    self.resourceData = [NSMutableData data];
  }
  else
  {
    NSLog(@"Connection failed: IMageViewerViewController");
  }
}

-(void)loadView
{
  self.filesize = [[NSNumber alloc]init];
  self.progressBar = [[UIProgressView alloc]initWithProgressViewStyle:UIProgressViewStyleBar];
  self.progressBar.frame = CGRectMake(20, 240, 280, 40);
  [self.progressBar setProgress:0.0];
  self.theImageView = [[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen]applicationFrame]]autorelease];
  self.theScrollView = [[[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen]applicationFrame]]autorelease];
  self.theScrollView.delegate = self;
  [self.theScrollView addSubview:self.theImageView];
  self.view = self.theScrollView;
  self.theLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 200, 320, 40)];
  self.theLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15.0f];
  self.theLabel.text = @"Please wait, file is being downloaded";
  self.theLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
  self.theLabel.hidden = NO;
  [self.view addSubview:self.progressBar];
  [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.progressBar];
  [self.view addSubview:self.theLabel];
  [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.    theLabel];
  [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setImageInImageView) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
}
```

And the header file:

```
@interface ImageViewerViewController : UIViewController<UIScrollViewDelegate, NSURLConnectionDelegate, NSURLConnectionDataDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *theImageView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIScrollView *theScrollView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *imageLink;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage *theImage;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *theLabel;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIProgressView *progressBar;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableData *resourceData;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *filesize;
@end
```

Hope it helps

Comment: do you know why that viewForZoomingInScrollView is never called?

Comment: @adit it is called by the UIScrollViewDelegate I believe

Comment: This is basically a reformed version of the zoomingPDFViwer by the looks of it, it is better. I have a question for @Novarg. When I load PDF this why from a tableview onto a scrollview it downloads but does not update the scrollview the first time it is selected but works on the second time why is this?

Comment: @mattInman it might be pretty much the same as zoomingPDFViewer, I just gathered a lot of code and then used pieces from these codes to create my class as I want it. And sorry, I didn't understand your question. Could you be more specific please? And this class was made to show images(jpg/jpeg/gif/bmp/png/etc.), so I'm not sure it will work with PDFs.

Comment: @Novarg Its OK i found my answer.

Comment: @Novarg I've tried your code.I'm having trouble to load image everything is working perfectly but not able to show my Image.(just black screen)Any idea how?

Answer (score 9):

I guess this answer may be unnecessary but I have had similar problems as @adit and solved it in a very simple way (I think) and maybe someone with similar challenges can use it:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];

    UIImage *imageToLoad = [UIImage imageNamed:@"background_green"];

    self.myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:imageToLoad];
    self.myScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    [self.myScrollView addSubview:self.myImageView];
    self.myScrollView.contentSize = self.myImageView.bounds.size;
    self.myScrollView.indicatorStyle = UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleWhite;
    self.myScrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.3f;
    self.myScrollView.maximumZoomScale = 3.0f;
    self.myScrollView.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:self.myScrollView];
}

- (UIView *) viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    NSLog(@"viewForZoomingInScrollView");
    return self.myImageView;
}
```

My problem was a very simple I had forgot to add `self.myScrollView.delegate = self;`, which was the reason why i had problems. It took me forever to figure that simple problem out, i guess I did not see the forrest for all the trees :-)

Answer (score 2):

When I was developing my Zooming PDF viewer in a UIScrollView I found out that when running it on the Phone it actually already has the zooming implemented as part of the phone. But you could have a look at this, http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ZoomingPDFViewer/Introduction/Intro.html it is a piece of sample code that tries to implement the functionality for zooming, this is want got me started.

Comment: I actually looked at that and it says that I will need a delegate called viewForZoomingInScrollView, however this is never called although I already set the delegate to self

Comment: Like @Novarg hassaid it gets called by the UIScrollViewDelegate so in your .h file make sure to add <UIScrollViewDelegate>

Answer (score 0):

For 'snap-image-to-screen-edges' solution @Shrikant Tanwade's worked well, but I wanted some insets. I tried settings constraints' constants, but that does not worked.

I ended with following solution:

1. same as for Shrikant's - set `scrollView`, `imageView`'s constraints, set their constants to `0`.
2. set insets with `scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(....`