# image view doesnt zoom in

Tags: iphone, uiimageview

in my app I have a view controller with an image view in it. But whenever I go there for some reason I can't zoom in or zoom out. What can be the problem?

code:

```
-(void)loadView {
  UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"testImage.png"]];
  [self.view addSubview:imgView];
  [self.view bringSubviewToFront:imgView];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had the same problem a while ago. I fixed it by adding an `UIScrollView` between `self.view` and `imgView`. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8891498/1047258) you can find the code I used. Please note that I was setting `imageLink` variable before pushing that view controller.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

have you tried to put your uiimageview inside a `UIScrollView`?